# How to create a tar.xz archive containing a directory and a hidden file in its root?

Tags: command-line, tar, compression

I've got a directory that contains a directory (with subdirectories and files) and a hidden (with a dot in front of its name) file. e.g:

```
dir1\
-- dir2\...
-- .hiddenFile
```

How do I create a tar.xz archive that would contain `dir2` and `.hiddenFile`in its root (not `dir1` nor `.`)?

I have googled a lot and tried a number of solutions but none helped.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid `dir1` appearing in the archive, you can run `tar` from inside it; and to avoid `.` as the leading element of the stored paths, don’t name it. There are two ways of going about this:

```
cd dir1
tar cvfJ ../archive.tar.xz dir2 .hiddenFile
```

or

```
tar cvfJ archive.tar.xz -C dir1 dir2 .hiddenFile
```

(*without* the `cd` — `-C` tells `tar` to change directories itself, when it reads it, so `archive.tar.xz` is created in the current directory but `dir2` and `.hiddenFile` are relative to `dir1`).

This produces an archive containing

```
dir2/
.hiddenFile
```

(along with `dir2`’ contents).